# Understanding destructuring with for...of

Tags: javascript

Looking through Atom's source code, I found this use of the `for..of` statement:

```
for (const {name, duration, x} of results) {
    dataByBenchmarkName[name] = dataByBenchmarkName[name] || {points: []}
    dataByBenchmarkName[name].points.push({x, y: duration})
}
```

I'm trying to replicate this iteration in the terminal, but the block never executes (as if I'm missing a bracket). I've tried iterating over objects (shallow, and deep), and arrays. When I take the curly brackets out, the statement works as documented. Can anyone give me a working example with brackets to learn from? Something simple like:

```
var test = ...; 
for(var {x,y,z} of test) {
    console.log(x);
};
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens in that first code sample depends on the value of `results`.

Comment: `var test = ...;` ??? what?? it needs to be an Array

Comment: The question in the title is not what you are really asking. please change to `help understanding Atom's source code for..of`

Comment: `{x,y,z}` is a destructuring assigment, it relies on each iterable having matching keys, i.e. `x`, `y` and `z`

Comment: Firefox gives me a syntax error when I try `const` in that code, but it works with `let`. (*edit*  Chrome is fine with `const`, so I suppose it's a Firefox bug.)

Comment: Yep, [bug 1101653](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1101653).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curly braces are just for [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
This works for me:

```js
var test = [{x:1,y:2,z:4}, {x:5, y:6,z:7}]; 
for(var {x,y,z} of test)
   console.log(x,y,z);
```

Output:

```
1 2 4
5 6 7
```

Answer (score 2):

This works

```js
var test = [{x:1,y:3,z:2},{x:5,y:6,z:3}]
for(var {x,y,z} of test) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks just saw you were first.

Comment: @Onyooo - being first doesn't mean anything if others answers are better, since this page will be viewed by thousands who will seek an answer, and they deserve to get the **best** answer, not the first.